# encrypt in php and decrypt in sql server

Tags: php, sql-server, php-openssl

Is it possible encrypt a data in php with `openssl_encrypt` and decrypt with a SP in sql server?

This is my data:

```
$idPer=openssl_encrypt($_POST["txt_id_permiso"],"AES-128-ECB","some");
```

Comment: it's possible encrypt a data in php with openssl_encrypt ?   yes we can

Comment: @suresh ... yes but the other half of the question is *"and decrypt with a stored procedure in SQL Server"* ...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cryptographic-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: You would need write a [scalar CLR function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-functions/clr-scalar-valued-functions?view=sql-server-2017) for this